# PHP is_numeric validation not catching letters

Tags: php, validation

The following function is supposed to allow empty an empty field to pass the test, allow a positive integer to pass the test, fail the test if a field contains any letters:

```
function fnValidatePositiveInteger($v)
{
    return (!empty($v) and (!is_numeric($v) or $v < 0 or $v != round($v))) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

However, it is behaving this way: it allows an empty field to pass the test, it allows positive integers to pass the test, but it also allows a field containing letters to pass and it should not.  How can this be fixed?

Comment: instead use `is_int()` ,because `is_numeric()` will also accept hexadecimel number )_for eg: it will accept __4c3__ because it is a valid hexadecimel_)

Comment: use regular expressions instead

Comment: try echo this line to see which are true and which are false for your incorrect case..

Comment: But is_int() won't accept string values containing valid numeric data (eg received from an html form via $_POST)

Comment: then better way is to use regex

Comment: This function is used to validate form data which comes through as string.  Unfortunately, is_int() causes an integer that comes through in string format to fail which is not the desired result.  Thanks, Pranav, for explaining why is_numeric() is not flagging letters mixed in with numbers.

Comment: You should find that using [filter_input()](http://www.php.net/function.filter-input) with FILTER_VALIDATE_INT can handle some of this validation

Comment: use __preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $v)__ ,which will return true if it's a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
function fnValidatePositiveInteger($v) 
{
    return (!empty($v) and (!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $v) or $v < 0 or $v != round($v))) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var) with a range to check if the number is a positive integer

```
function fnValidatePositiveInteger($v)
{
    $is_int = filter_var($v, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
        'options' => array('min_range' => 1)
    ));
    return $v == '' || $is_int;
}
```

Test cases:

```
var_dump(fnValidatePositiveInteger(''));    // bool(true)
var_dump(fnValidatePositiveInteger(42));    // bool(true)
var_dump(fnValidatePositiveInteger(-50));   // bool(false)
var_dump(fnValidatePositiveInteger('Ab'));  // bool(false)
```